# Zend Framework 2 IntlDateFormatter not show date in view

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, intl

I have installed the INTL in my apache with Yosemite OSX [image]

In my database, set the Date 
[image]

But in my View this date doesn't show, why?

```
<?php 
        echo $this->dateFormat($post['post_date'], \IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, \IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, 'en_US');
      ?>
```

[image]

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `$post['post_date']` in this case? Did you try `echo($post['post_date']);` already, maybe it is empty?

Comment: Date must be one of described value params [here](http://php.net/manual/de/intldateformatter.format.php#refsect1-intldateformatter.format-parameters).

Comment: `$post['post_date']` this may be a `DateTime` object, an integer representing a Unix timestamp value or an array in the format output by `localtime()`. http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.i18n.view.helpers.html#dateformat-helper